# Passing params using redirect to different action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is first action in controller:

```
def investor_following
  @investor = params[:user][:investor_id]
  # blah
end

def change_amount
  investor = "xyz"
  redirect to :action => :investor_following, :user[:investor_id] => investor
end
```

I am getting error how can I redirect to action investor following, what would be right syntax to do with params.

Comment: `:user[:investor_id]` is not correct syntax.

Comment: YEah I know can you tell what is the right syntax i tried bit didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a named route for your action in your routes.rb. I'm not sure what you investor_following function will do, so I am not certain if it should be a GET, POST, or PATCH. If you intend to modify your model, use a POST/PATCH, if not, use a get.

Once you have a named route, you will get a path helper like investor_following_path which you can send parameters as ruby objects:

```
#routes.rb
get '/investor_following', to: 'controllername#investor_following', as: 'investor_following'

#in your controller
redirect_to investor_following_path(user: {investor_id: investor})
```

This is untested but in general what you should do.

Here is info on redirect_to:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Here is the info on routing for your named path:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html